# Green eyes / green eyed / eyes vocabulary

Tags: vocabulary

I am wondering what's the most usual to say between

> he got green eyes
>   his eyes are green
>   he is green eyed

Does it depends on the English speaking country?
I am also wondering about the eyes vocabulary, for example hazel (which means brown and green eyes) does not exist in French.

Comment: _J'ai les yeux noisettes!_ "Hazel" certainly **does** exist in French.

Comment: 'Hazel eyes' look like (usually green and brown) that https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Hazel_eye1.png  but in french 'yeux noisettes' is more a light brown https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/92/62/93/926293376e66248c3a6f42cccc870503.jpg . For me it's 2 different colors because hazel always means green + brown and noisettes often means brown but can in some specific cases means brown + blue / green

Comment: I was thinking of "Jade eyes", but if said quickly, it might become a reference to light-saber-wielding characters.

Comment: Green-eyed should be hyphenated.

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain about other English-speaking countries (I'm in the U.S.), but here is my answer:

1. He got green eyes:  You might hear "He**'s** got green eyes" which is informal, but correct.
2. His eyes are green:  Correct usage, probably heard in response to a direct question "What color are his eyes?"
3. He is green-eyed:  Also correct, but a construction less commonly heard in the U.S.

Comment: In UK English "He got green eyes" sounds slangish. The past tense seems incorrect to me. "He has green eyes" or "He has got green eyes" sounds better, the latter shortened to "He's got green eyes".

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

> He *has* green eyes.
>   His eyes are green.

These are normally used.

> He is green eyed.

*eyed* is usually used as an modifier, as in [Brown Eyed Girl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_Eyed_Girl). I would not use it by itself.

Answer (score 0):

The vocabulary:

We use "brown", "green" and "blue" as common descriptions of eye colour. "Grey" (a variant of blue), "amber" (lighter brown without green) and "hazel" (brown and green) also specific. Some people avoid "black" since it could be confused with the black eye that boxers (etc) get. But Black is still a common way of describing eye colour. Beyond this, people can be creative in describing their eyes.

I have heard that "maroon" is used in the USA for "dark chestnut coloured eyes"

Comment: I live in the US and never heard of "maroon eyes"